# Fetch data and arrange sequence in given format

Tags: php, database, array, data, sort

This is my array:

```
<?php
$sku = ['HH017','HH018','HH005','HH010','20OZHHTUMBLER',
        '30OZTUMBLER2','HH006','HH-05'];

$sequence = ['HH005','HH010','HH006','20OZHHTUMBLER',...];

print_r(sort($sku, $sequence));

?>
```

I want to arrange that data of $sku in $sequence format.
I want to show the first 4 numbers from `$sku`, as mentioned in `$sequence` and then the remaining numbers will be shown after these 4 numbers.

How can I arrange the sequence to show my data in this format?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sequencedValues = [];

$sku = ['HH017','HH018','HH005','HH010','20OZHHTUMBLER',
        '30OZTUMBLER2','HH006','HH-05'];

$sequence = ['HH005','HH010','HH006','20OZHHTUMBLER'];

foreach ($sequence as $value) {
    if (in_array($value, $sku)) {
        $sequencedValues[] = $value;
        unset($sku[array_search($value, $sku)];
    }
}

$sequencedValues = array_merge($sequencedValues, $sku);
```

Probably a more efficient way to do it but that should work. This isn't a Magento specific question so shouldn't really be in the Magento stack exchange.